# MATLAB: Concatenate number value as string

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, concatenation

I want to create a binary number in matlab and am having difficulty concatenating the numbers.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
testarray = zeros(10,10)
testarray = num2str(testarray) % Convert all values to type string

testarray(1,1) = num2str(1); % Fill with abitrary value

testarray(1,1) = strcat(testarray(1,1), num2str(0)); % Trying to make '10' here but instead I get this error: "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the problem is that `'10'` has size [1,2], but testarray(1,1) has size [1,1]. So you might consider using cells instead:

```
testarray = cell(5,5);
testarray{1,1} = strcat(testarray(1,1), num2str(0));
```

By the way, you should have a look at the function `dec2bin`.

From the documentation:

```
dec2bin(23)
ans =
    10111
```

The resulting value is a **string**.

So if you want to concatenate two binary values (encoded as strings), just do:

```
['10' '11']
ans =
    1011
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used the cell method and that worked.